# How to use blueprint programmatically?

Tags: osgi, blueprint-osgi

Is it possible to wire blueprint services not by using XML (declaratively), but in the runtime? 
What I want is an interface simmilar creating a [BeanDefinition](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html)

```
ctx.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, BeanDefinition)
```

Somehow this should be called from a separate bundle that would start/stop services from other bundles

Comment: What purpose would this serve?  There is already an API for registering/consuming services, which in essence is what Blueprint and DS do delcaratively.

Comment: And why not use normal plain old Java? The primary advantage of DI engines is the ordering you get, fail to understand why you ever want to play after this process has already happened?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to lookup the blueprint context of your bundle since it's a registered service, and from there on you should be able to just do what you like with registering beans and so fort.